# for loop with "<-" to create variables in R

Tags: r

So I have this data :

```
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,ncol=3))
```

which gives this :

```
| V1 | V2 | V3 |  
________________  
|  1 | 2  | 3  | 
|  4 | 5  | 6  |
|  7 | 8  | 9  |
```

I want to create a variable for each column to get this :

```
> V1
[1] 1 2 3

> V2
[1] 4 5 6

> V3
[1] 7 8 9
```

I know that if I do a loop with the assign function :

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
               assign(names(data[i]),data[,i])
               
}
```

it works. But if I try with the "<-" :

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
           names(data[i])<-data[,i]
           
}
```

it does not work.
Why does it work with the assign function but not with the "<-" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `list2env`

```
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

-check for objects

```
V1
#[1] 1 2 3
V2
#[1] 4 5 6
V3
#[1] 7 8 9
```

---

In the `for` loop, it can be looped over the column names and use `assign`

```
for(nm in names(data)) assign(nm, data[[nm]])
```

---

The `names` assignment works only for assigning the column names or `names` attribute of a `vector` and not create an object.  The error is basically about the difference in `length` of the `lhs` and `rhs` of the assignment (`<-`) operator

```
names(data[1])
#[1] "V1"
```

Better would be

```
names(data)[1]
```

and

```
data[,1]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

is the value of the column which is of `length` 3

when we assign `<-`) it to the `names(data)[1]`, it is assigning the first column name to `1 2 3` which differs in `length`

```
names(data)[1] <- data[,1]
```

> Warning message: In names(data)[1] <- data[, 1] :   number of items to
> replace is not a multiple of replacement length

returns a warning, but if we use the OP's method of subsetting

```
names(data[1]) <- data[,1]
```

> Error in names(data[1]) <- data[, 1] :    'names' attribute [3] must
> be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but what I do still not understand is WHY this loop does not work with "<-".

Comment: @123123123 You are assigning to column name with the value of a column and the lengths are not the same `'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

Comment: @123123123 In the first iteration i.e. `names(data[1])` it is the column name of the first column. The value of that column is on the rhs i.e. `data[,1]` which is a vector of length 3.  Basically you are trying to assign the first column name with the 1, 2, 3 which is of length 3

Comment: So when I tried ```names(data[i])<-data[,i]``` I tried to change the name of the column instead of assigning the column name to a vector ?

Comment: @123123123 I updated with some explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `lapply` to keep your vectors as a list.  (Easier to reference):

```
nrows <- nrow(data)
nrows
3
vecs <- lapply(1:nrows, function(x) data[x, ])
vecs
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3
2  2  5  8

[[3]]
  V1 V2 V3
3  3  6  9
```